# Scipy.optimize - curve fitting with fixed parameters

Tags: numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm performing curve fitting with `scipy.optimize.leastsq`. E.g. for a gaussian:

```
def fitGaussian(x, y, init=[1.0,0.0,4.0,0.1]):
    fitfunc = lambda p, x: p[0]*np.exp(-(x-p[1])**2/(2*p[2]**2))+p[3] # Target function
    errfunc = lambda p, x, y: fitfunc(p, x) - y # Distance to the target function
    final, success = scipy.optimize.leastsq(errfunc, init[:], args=(x, y))
    return fitfunc, final
```

Now, I want to optionally fix the values of some of the parameters in the fit. I found that suggestions are to use a different package [lmfit](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/intro.html), which I want to avoid, or are very general, like [here](http://scipy-user.10969.n7.nabble.com/curve-fitting-with-fixed-parameters-td3310.html).
Since I need a solution which

1. works with numpy/scipy (no further packages etc.)
2. is independent of the parameters themselves,
3. is flexible, in which parameters are fixed or not,

I came up with the following, using a condition on each of the parameters:

```
def fitGaussian2(x, y, init=[1.0,0.0,4.0,0.1], fix = [False, False, False, False]):
    fitfunc = lambda p, x: (p[0] if not fix[0] else init[0])*np.exp(-(x-(p[1] if not fix[1] else init[1]))**2/(2*(p[2] if not fix[2] else init[2])**2))+(p[3] if not fix[3] else init[3]) 
    errfunc = lambda p, x, y: fitfunc(p, x) - y # Distance to the target function
    final, success = scipy.optimize.leastsq(errfunc, init[:], args=(x, y))
    return fitfunc, final
```

While this works fine, it's neither practical, nor beautiful. 
So my question is: Are there better ways of performing curve fitting in scipy for fixed parameters? Or are there wrappers, which already include such parameter fixing?

Comment: Would be nice to have this functionality in scipy, but I am not sure if it exists. Out of curiosity, why do you want to avoid lmfit? It's quite straightforward to use in my experience.

Comment: The reason I want to avoid other packages, is that I would need to make sure they are properly installed on any of the computers this program runs on.

Answer (score 2):

Using `scipy`, there are no builtin options that I am aware of. You will always have to do a work-around like the one you already did.

If you are willing to use a wrapper package however, may I recommend my own [`symfit`](http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#simple-example)? This is a wrapper to `scipy` with readability and less boilerplate code as its core principles. In [`symfit`](http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#simple-example), your problem would be solved as:

```
from symfit import parameters, variables, exp, Fit, Parameter

a, b, c, d = parameters('a, b, c, d')
x, y = variables('x, y')

model_dict = {y: a * exp(-(x - b)**2 / (2 * c**2)) + d}

fit = Fit(model_dict, x=xdata, y=ydata)
fit_result = fit.execute()
```

The line `a, b, c, d = parameters('a, b, c, d')` makes four `Parameter` objects. To fix e.g. the parameter `c` to its initial value, do the following anywhere before calling `fit.execute()`:

```
c.value = 4.0
c.fixed = True
```

So a possible end result might be:

```
from symfit import parameters, variables, exp, Fit, Parameter

a, b, c, d = parameters('a, b, c, d')
x, y = variables('x, y')

c.value = 4.0
c.fixed = True

model_dict = {y: a * exp(-(x - b)**2 / (2 * c**2)) + d}

fit = Fit(model_dict, x=xdata, y=ydata)
fit_result = fit.execute()
```

If you want to be more dynamic in your code, you could make the `Parameter` objects straight away using:

```
c = Parameter(4.0, fixed=True)
```

For more info, check the docs: http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#simple-example

Answer (score 0):

The above example using symfit would surely simply the syntax of the fitting approach, however, does the example given really constrain the variable c?

If you look at the `fit_result.param` you get the following:

`OrderedDict([('a', 16.374368575343127),
                 ('b', 0.49201249437123556),
                 ('c', 0.5337962977235504),
                 ('d', -9.55593614465743)])`

The parameter c is not 4.0.

Comment: This is not really an answer, is it? Instead you might comment on the other answer to ask for clarification. But in any case, symfit is not what this question asks for.

Comment: This turned out to be a bug in 0.4.0 and has now been fixed :). But @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is right in that this should be a comment to my answer, not a seperate answer.